# I am stuck on a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Write a query to list the different offices (their address), count of the number of employees at that office and the number of orders that employees at that office were sales representatives for.

So far this is what I have come up with in mysql:

```
SELECT Offices.addressLine1,
        Offices.addressLine2, 
        COUNT(Employees.employeeNumber),
        COUNT(Orders.orderNumber)
   FROM Offices,
        Employees,
        Customers,
        Orders
   WHERE Offices.officeCode=Employees.officeCode AND
          Employees.employeeNumber=Customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber AND
          Customers.customerNumber=Orders.customerNumber
   GROUP BY addressLine1;
```

http://www.richardtwatson.com/dm6e/images/general/ClassicModels.png

Here is also the link to the data models that I am using for reference. I know my code is not completely correct but I am stuck in regards of how to connect the all of the tables together in a way that makes sense so any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What output you got with this query. And try `group by Offices.addressLine1, Offices.addressLine2;`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You typically group by the columns you select, except those who arguments to set functions!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as below:

```
SELECT o.officecode
    ,o.addressLine1
    ,o.addressLine2
    ,count(e.employeeNumber)
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN o.orderNumber IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS TotalOrders
FROM Offices AS o
INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON o.officecode = e.officecode
LEFT JOIN Customers AS c ON c.salesRepEmployeeNumber = e.employeeNumber
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
GROUP BY o.officecode
    ,o.addressLine1
    ,o.addressLine2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following

```
SELECT 
Offices.officeCode,
Offices.addressLine1,
Offices.addressLine2,
COUNT(ISNULL(Employees.employeeNumber,0)) AS EmpCount,
COUNT(ISNULL(Orders.OrderNumber,0)) AS NoOfOrders    
FROM
Offices
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Offices.officeCode = Employees.officeCode
LEFT JOIN Customers
ON Employees.employeeNumber = Customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
GROUP BY 
Offices.officeCode,
Offices.addressLine1,
Offices.addressLine2
```

Answer (score 0):

When aggregating across multiple tables there is a chance  you will get incorrect results. Here you need to count `distinct` employees orherwise that count would be inflated by the number of orders. Note that the count function ignores NULL so there is no need to compensate for NULL but you do need left joins on customere/orders to ensure all employees are counted.

```
SELECT
      o.officecode
    , o.addressLine1
    , o.addressLine2
    , count(distinct e.employeeNumber)
    , count(o.orderNumber) AS TotalOrders
FROM Offices AS o
INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON o.officecode = e.officecode
LEFT JOIN Customers AS c ON c.salesRepEmployeeNumber = e.employeeNumber
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
GROUP BY
      o.officecode
    , o.addressLine1
    , o.addressLine2
```